# jQuery object-oriented created dom element and add event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, execute

I have a little problem. I've created some element in an object and that works fine. But now I want to add some EventListeners to execute a function inner my object, the problem is that I cannot execute the function "setSelection". ("this" is not the "this" of the object, but the "this" of the event inner the click-function).

```
function Object() {
    this.init = function () {
        // delete table
        // ...
        // set table
        $('tr').append('<td id="1">test</td>');

        $('td').click(function() {
            // execute setSelection
        });
    }

    this.setSelection = function(x) {
        alert('You clicked id ' + x);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    x = new Object();
    x.init();
});
```

Comment: it can lead to problems to override the `Object` function, if you know what you are doing, fine, or else, you should rename it. For your problem, what causes this is that event callbacks are executed in the global context. This is why the proposed answers work, you need either to store the context in a var, or use functions as `bind`, `apply` or such to get the context back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by storing the reference of `this` in the outer scope to a variable that you can use in the `click` event handler:

```
function Object() {
    var _this = this;

    this.init = function () {
        // delete table
        // ...
        // set table
        $('tr').append('<td id="1">test</td>');

        $('td').click(function() {
            _this.doSomething();
        });
    }

    this.setSelection = function(x) {
        alert('You clicked id ' + x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('td').click((function(e) {
        // execute setSelection
        this.setSelection(...);
    }).bind(this));
```

Comment: This would work, but it would mean that you would need to use `e.target` to get a reference to the `td` which was clicked, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be:

```
function Object() {
  this.init = function () {
    // delete table
    // ...
    // set table
    $('tr').append('<td id="1">test</td>');

    $('td').click(function() {
      setSelection(this);
    });
  }

  setSelection = function(x) {
    alert('You clicked id ' + x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem...

```
function Object() {
    this.init = function () {
        // delete table
        // ...
        // set table
        $('tr').append('<td id="1">test</td>');

        this.setSelection();
    }

    this.setSelection = function() {
       $('td').click(function() {
            alert('You clicked id ' + $(this).attr('id'));
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    x = new Object();
    x.init();
});
```

Comment: This is not a solution to your question. And this is wrong - every call of `setSelection` adds a new `click` handler to `td` elements. All these handlers will be executed in sequence the next time your click.